# Scala program to replace words in an alphabetical order with in a string

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and have been trying to create a program which should replace characters in each word with in a string in an alphabetical order. For example, the string is "Where are you" so program should change it to "Eehrw aer ouy". I googled search and found some examples but I am not able to write an error free program. I think I am far from having a working program.

```
def main(args:Array[String]){
    val r = "Where are you"
    val newstr = r.map(x=>(x,_) match {
      case ' ' =   ' '
      case y =>  {
        val newchar = (x.toByte).toChar
        if newchar.toByte.toChar > (newchar + 1).toByte.toChar
        x = newchar
        else
        x
      }
   })
     }
```

Comment: You're doing operations on the character level, which is making things hard for you. `r.map` is doing a map on each character in the entire string. What you probably want to do is instead split your initial string by spaces (`r.split( " ")`), then map over and modify those individual words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is restoring the original capitalization. Add punctuation to the mix and it turns into a fun little challenge.

```
val str = "Where, aRe yoU?"
val sortedLowerCase = str.toLowerCase.split("(?=\\W)").map(_.sorted).mkString
val capsAt = str.indices.filter(str(_).isUpper)
capsAt.foldLeft(sortedLowerCase)((s,x) => s.patch(x,Seq(s(x).toUpper),1))
// res0: String = Eehrw, aEr ouY?
```

Time spent studying the [Standard Library](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/) will be richly rewarded.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh. That is really helpful. Thanks for providing the link to Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

`r.split(" ").map(word => word.toLowerCase.sorted)`

To keep the capital letters, instead of .toLowerCase.sorted, used .sortWith and implement the sort comparison function according to how you want to sort characters.

Comment: Thanks @Ren. Your input is commendable. Adds to my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand on Ren's answer:

compare based on lowercase and then capitalize only if there's an uppercase letter

```
r.split(" ").map(word => word.sortWith(_.toLower < _.toLower))
  .map(x => if (x.exists(_.isUpper)) x.toLowerCase.capitalize else x )
```